# Python - Error with writing into a file opened in binary mode

Tags: python, file, networking, server, client

I'm trying to write a server-client program where the client reads from a file opened in binary mode and then sends it to the server which writes the data into another file in binary mode ('wb+').

The main part of the code where the error occurs is:

```
print(fileData)
newFile.write(fileData)
```

And the output from this is:

```
b'Hello World!\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ftps.py", line 37, in <module>

    newFile.write(fileData)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Now I think I understand what the error is. The b'Hello World!\n' is of type string and must be in binary format before i can write it to the file. So I tried using fileData[2:-1].encode('utf-8') in order to convert it to binary object but it still wouldn't let me write into the text file. (The error no longer shows up but nothing gets written into the file. Is there some other way to do this or am I on the right path (trying to convert the string into a binary object?). Thanks!

Edit: Sorry for not being clear the first time around but I don't specifically need to write the "hello world" string but just gave it as an example. The actual code has these 2 lines in a while loop and keeps printing different strings. And I'm using Python 3!

Comment: What python version are you using? And why the slice `fileData[2:-1]`?

Comment: You are on Python 3, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: Ok, something isn't adding up. The string you are printing is a bytes object, that's why the b is in it when it is printed `b"hello"`. If you tried to actually `encode` that, it would raise an AttributeError. We need to see a more complete picture of your code. Preferebly a self-contained example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Also, the reason it might not be writing anything is because the string has a length less than 3, so when you do `fileData[2:-1]` it returns an empty string. That, or you aren't closing your file. Also, it's `bytes` object, not "binary object".

Answer (score 1):

`.encode('utf-8')` does not create a binary object.

It seems like you're not converting the "Hello World!" to binary at all. 
Try this:

```
>>> st = "Hello World!"
>>> map(bin, bytearray(st))
['0b1001000', '0b1100101', '0b1101100', '0b1101100', '0b1101111', '0b100000', '0b1010111', '0b1101111', '0b1110010', '0b1101100', '0b1100100', '0b100001']
```

You should be able to write the result to your file.

Comment: No, now you just string representations of binary numbers... `encode` *should* create a bytes object, which is what is required, not a "binary object" (which isn't a type in Python)

Comment: Oh, I must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that the "hello world" is just an example. The actual code is printing out various strings that it receives from a loop.

Comment: Sebastin can you provide some more code to make this clearer?